# continuous speech to text in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a speech to text component. it is working but when i stop talking it stops also , but i want a loop until i press stop button .

```
const SpeechRecognition =
      window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

This is the code i have tried - https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-clarke-4z7eqb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want but here is how to continuously play the text.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [voice, setVoice] = React.useState(false);

  const speek = () => {
    const SpeechRecognition =
      window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    if (voice) recognition.start();
    else recognition.stop();
    recognition.onresult = (event) => {
      const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
      console.log(transcript);
    };
    recognition.onspeechend = () => {
      recognition.stop();
      if (voice === true) speek(voice); // loop
    };
    recognition.onerror = (event) => {
      console.log("error");
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    speek(voice);
  }, [voice]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setVoice(!voice)}>
        {voice ? "stop" : "start"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is codebase https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cray-igzrb7?file=/src/App.js:0-886